# No serializer found error while serializing List<Object>

Tags: java, spring, jackson

I have a class

```
public class ClassB 
{

    private ClassC c;

    private List<ClasssA> a;

}
```

which I am returning in my controller method as response body. When I add @JsonIgnore to List object, I am getting response but when I include List, I am getting error as

```
Could not write content: No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) ) (through reference chain: ......
```

Comment: What happens when you disable FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS like the error message suggests?

Comment: I just tested by disabling FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS. I am getting data which I don't have in my class like "handler": {}, "hibernateLazyInitializer": {} and missing some data. Trying to figure out what's happening

Comment: @Raghavendra Have you tried with my answer or nothing?

Answer (score 0):

This a common problem with

> lazy Hibernate loading: Hibernate won’t load the relationships for that particular object instance.

So that's why the error you get. Now the common solution and reported bug is Use this property

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
```

Check more of this [Bug Reported](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/OGM-641?attachmentOrder=desc) and more [Lazy vs Eager](https://howtoprogramwithjava.com/hibernate-eager-vs-lazy-fetch-type/)